# How to read value of string structured variable

Tags: php, string

I try to read value of a string return of a function with var_dump to after prinf this value in my header web page, I explain:

```
public static function login(User $usr,$password){
       if($usr->getPassword() == $password){
           $r["error"] = 0;
           self::StartSessionNow($usr);
       }else{
           $r["error"] = 1;
       }
       return $r;
}
```

from another class call this fuction:

```
$r = json_encode(Users_bl::login($usr,filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password")));
```

and I try read value 1 or 0 with var_dump($r) the print result is:

```
string(11) "{"error":1}"
```

but I want print value only not error text, I tried with `var_dump($r['error'])`, but print result is:

```
string(1) "{"
```

Do you have any idea of how to print value only?

Comment: Don't `json_encode` it. `$r = Users_bl::login($usr,filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"))['error'];`

Comment: Also, why use `$r["error"]` if you don't use it?  Just return `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don`t use json_encode, unless you need return the response to ajax or API.

chage:

```
$r = json_encode(Users_bl::login($usr,filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password")));
```

to:

```
$r = Users_bl::login($usr,filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"));
var_dump($r['error'])
```